# how to do simple concat in awk in mac

Tags: macos, shell, sed, awk

So I have a file list.txt similar to this one:

```
                              186
                              423
                              423
                              234
                              634
                              437
```

And I want an output similar to this:

```
SET 186 0
SET 423 0
SET 423 0
SET 234 0
SET 634 0
SET 437 0
```

I tried with this:

```
sed 's/^ *//g' list.txt | awk '{a="SET ";b=" 0";print a,$0,b}'
```

But it prints

```
  0 186
  0 423
  0 423
  0 234
  0 634
  0 437
```

Given that

```
sed 's/^ *//g' list.txt | awk '{a="SET ";b=" 0";print a,$0}'
```

Works perfect:

```
SET 186
SET 423
SET 423
SET 234
SET 634
SET 437
```

So I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Do you know how to solve this and why `print a,$0,b` doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because your input file was created on Windows and so has spurious control-Ms at the end of each line and that's messing up the displayed output. Run `dos2unix` on the file or otherwise get rid of those control-Ms and your script would work as written, but a better way to do it would be simply:

```
awk '{print "SET",$1,0}' list.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

With awk, its:

```
awk '{printf "SET %d 0\n", $1}' your.file
```

Comment: `printf` does not print a newline, you have to add it to the format string.

Answer (score 2):

Simply:

```
$ awk '{print "SET",$1,0}' file
SET 186 0
SET 423 0
SET 423 0
SET 234 0
SET 634 0
SET 437 0
```

Answer (score 2):

try this awk one-liner:

```
awk '$0="SET "$1" 0"' file
```

outpus:

```
SET 186 0
SET 423 0
SET 423 0
SET 234 0
SET 634 0
SET 437 0
```

Comment: Would you like to read your script or this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18411951/171318 ? I prefer the latter one

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print "SET", $1, "0"}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This sed with inline switch `-i` works:

```
sed -i.bak 's/\([0-9]*\)/SET \1 0/' file
```

`-i.bak` will make sure to save changes into the file with backup created with `.bak` extension.